# Python Help finding value of i

Tags: python, python-2.6

What is the value of i at the end of the loop body when a is 6?

```
def loopIdentification():
    i=0
    for a in range(2,8):
        i=i+a-3
    return i
```

Comment: Why don’t you just try that code and call that function?

Answer (score 1):

**5**

```
>>> def loopIdentification():
    i=0
    for a in range(2,8):
        i=i+a-3
        print a, i
    return i

>>> loopIdentification()
2 -1
3 -1
4 0
5 2
6 5
7 9
9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i appreciate it. I just did it in python and it spit out 5.

Comment: def sumlist(inputlist):
    listsum =0
    for item in inputlist:
        listsum = listsum + item
        return listsum

# YOUR DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM (in a comment)